# Why does the PDO constructor not take host, dbname, database type, etc.  as regular function arguments?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm learning about PDO, and the constructor seems to use an unorthodox and inconsistent way to take arguments. Namely:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

Why is different than the usual format:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql", $host, $dbname, $user, $pass);
```

Or since the first two arguments (host and dbname) are written as one long string, why not continue that with the remaining two arguments? Namely:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;user=$user;pass=$pass");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DSN describes where the data source resides and how to connect to it. User and pass are authentication parameters which do not have any affect on how the data source is accessed.

Having user and pass in the DSN would be like requiring your username and password in the url of a website you're going to.

Answer (score 0):

PDO uses DSNs to connect, the username and password are optional parameters to the DSN string.

check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

I dont really think this is "Unorthodox or inconsistent", ODBC in PHP uses the same process.

Comment: The reasoning was: "Unorthodox" because I've never encountered a PHP function that accepted arguments in such a manner, "Inconsistent" because it seemed like some arguments were accepted as a string and some as just variables. But I'll definitely look into DSNs. Thanks!

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, it is a lot different than the traditional way of calling mysql_connect() etc.